# How do I swap rows and cols of a numpy array without affecting the channels? (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with the following structure:

```
A = [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]
```

`A` has 4 rows, 2 cols and 3 channels (in the tuples). For short: `A.shape = (4, 2, 3)`

Now I need to swap the rows and cols **without affecting the channels**.
The output should look like this:

```
B = [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]
```

`B` has 2 rows, 4 cols and 3 channels (the tuples). For short: `B.shape = (2, 4, 3)`

The best I found in hours was this: `numpy.array(A).transpose()`
It worked for 1 of the image, but others suddenly had 480 channels XD (`A` is a simplified version of what I have) and just 3 rows.

So how do I do that?

Comment: Look into the `reshape` numpy method : e.g. `np.array(A).reshape(dim1, dim2, dim3)`

Comment: Transpose takes an order parameter, e.g.  `A.transpose(1,0,2)` will switch the first 2 dimensions, leaving the last, channels, last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible methods is to use the [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) method:

```
In [15]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 4, 3)

In [16]: A
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]]])

In [17]: A.shape
Out[17]: (2, 4, 3)

In [18]: B = A.swapaxes(0, 1)

In [19]: B.shape
Out[19]: (4, 2, 3)

In [20]: B
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [21, 22, 23]]])
```

Comment: Thank you! The swapaxes(0, 1) method works!

Answer (score 0):

Another method apart from `np.swapaxes` is using `np.transpose`

Check the documentation for [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose)  and [swapaxes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes) with basic examples

```
A = [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
     [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]

A = np.array(A)

C = np.transpose(A, (1, 0, 2)) # axes1 and axes2 are switching here which changes the shape from (4,2,3) to (2,4,3)

print(C)
```

Output :

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```